# Customize content of finish page in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to customize my finish page so I can have radio controls for user to choose what action to apply after finish page.

I tried various methods such as

`Page1 := CreateCustomPage(wpInfoAfter, 'test', 'test');`

and

`Page1 := CreateCustomPage(wpFinished, 'test', 'test');`

but none of them gives the result I want.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the result that you expect and what did you get instead ?

Comment: For Page1 := CreateCustomPage(wpInfoAfter, 'test', 'test');, I got a custom page before Finish page.

For Page1 := CreateCustomPage(wpFinished, 'test', 'test');, nothing was added.

I hope I can either
1. Fully customize the finish page
or
2. Add a page before finish page, and then get rid of finish page.

Comment: i got i got it. Just call CreateCustomPage(wpInfoAfter, 'test', 'test'); and  implement DisableFinishedPage

Comment: You could also modify wpFinished with `procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer); begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then begin
    //your changes here
  end;
end;`

Answer (score 1):

1. For customization of the existing page you have to add to your ISS script something like that:

From-scratch code, not compiled:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
    MyMsg: TLabel;
begin
    if (CurPageID <> wpFinished) then return;

    MyMsg := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
    MyMsg.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
    MyMsg.Caption := 'Hello World';
    MyMsg.AutoSize := True;
end;
```

To correctly position your label you need to take into account pre-defined controls. Luckily, InnoSetup is open-source product https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc
You can get a clue of what is contained on each wizard page via evaluating Wizard.pas and Wizard.dfm.txt files. So that, you'll be able to place correct MyMsg.Left and MyMsg.Top values.

2. If talking about "Custom page from scratch", it's much more complicated approach and again you'll need InnoSetup sources to guess what the system is expecting.

General idea:

```
constructor TWizardForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  ...
  { Initialize wpFinished page }
  RegisterExistingPage(wpFinished, FinishedPage, nil, '', '');
  SetFontNameSize(FinishedHeadingLabel.Font, LangOptions.WelcomeFontName,
    LangOptions.WelcomeFontSize, '', 12);
  FinishedHeadingLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  FinishedHeadingLabel.Caption := ExpandSetupMessage(msgFinishedHeadingLabel) + SNewLine;
  AdjustLabelHeight(FinishedHeadingLabel);
  FinishedLabel.Top := FinishedHeadingLabel.Top + FinishedHeadingLabel.Height;
  YesRadio.Caption := SetupMessages[msgYesRadio];
  NoRadio.Caption := SetupMessages[msgNoRadio];
  RunList.MinItemHeight := ScalePixelsY(22);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: You just blindly copied some random piece of Inno Setup source code, which is absolutely not usable in Inno Setup Code section. You cannot write methods, let only constructors. There's no `RegisterExistingPage`, `SetFontNameSize`, etc.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, if we talk about "approach #2" this is just general idea where to dig, nothing more. It's not a detailed recipe, sorry if I didn't emphasize it enough. "Approach #1" is absolutely working, the only lack of detail is layout relative position as clearly stated in the post.